# Sleep option missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep

After Updating to Windows , I'm missing the Sleep button in the Power options. I've tried to add it through  the Choose what the power button does, but it's also missing.

Answer (score 3):

Open a PowerShell window and type:
`powercfg -a`
this will probably tell you *why* it is not available.

In my case 'sleep' was missing because the hypervisor service disabled it. I got around it by uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

See if reset/restore all power plans to default will help. On command prompt:

```
powercfg -restoredefaultschemes
```

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo's answer is right, I tried nearly all general recommended methods I googled, finally solved this by `powercfg -a`, and it shows it's "graphics" that makes sleep missing. Then realize my Integrated Graphics was banned before, and for some reasons it stops sleep from working. So I go to device manager to enable Integrated Graphics, and it works.